# Fill an Access table from a large parsed string

Tags: c#, parsing, ms-access

After a week of studying C# I managed to build the parsing section of my program. But I need to take the info and fill an Access db with it. 
So far it's beating me. Looked at datagrid code but nothing seems to fit. And datagrid may not be what I need.
I want it to fill the actual table and not just create a view of it.

Below is the parsing code I made and I assume I would feed the data to the table at the point I have a messagebox.

The table is in my Data Source as AppDataDataSet1. Table t_Parse_Parts. Fields ParseBox, SR, Cust_Ref, Cust_Name, WB.

```
        // test for zero length
        if (TargetString.Length >0)
        {

            LocateInStr = TargetString.IndexOf("SR ");//case sensitive. find first occurence point

            if (LocateInStr > 0) //  verify first occurence point
            {
                EndStr = 0;
                string[] SrchFor = { "SR ", "Cust Ref ", "Cust Name ", "WB or PUDO ID " };
                int[] StepOver = {3,9,10,14};

                do
                {
                    for (int i=0; i<4; i++)
                    {
                        LocateInStr = TargetString.IndexOf(SrchFor[i], EndStr);
                        BeginStr = LocateInStr + StepOver[i];
                        EndStr = TargetString.IndexOf("\n", BeginStr)-1; //read to end of line
                        strSR = TargetString.Substring(BeginStr, EndStr-BeginStr);
                        strSR = strSR.TrimEnd();

                        MessageBox.Show(SrchFor[i] +" ->"+ strSR + "<- at " + LocateInStr.ToString());
                    }
                    LocateInStr = TargetString.IndexOf(SrchFor[0], EndStr);// Looks for another start point. Ends loop if not found.
                }
                while (LocateInStr > 0);
            }
        }
        this.ParseBox2.Text = "";
```

Off and on I've coded since the early 80's, Basic, FoxPro, Alpha4, to name a few. I use C# VS2013 Ultimate for web design but now wish to create executables. This is my first attempt at it. Converting a tool I made in Access to a C# version.

Comment: I suppose you need to set a connection to the db and run an SQL INSERT action.

Comment: Please try asking a single question. Is the parsing the data the problem, connecting with the database the problem, or inserting the data after you've formed the connection? Show us your attempts for each step.

Comment: The code above works fine in getting the individual pieces of information as tested by the messagebox. The table is in the  data source so I think the question is how to get the data to the table and form records.

Comment: I think you may be right about setting a connection and then an SQL statement. Will research.

Comment: Resolved, using connection and sql statement. also needed @ to use connection path with slashes.    Thanks